# Input validation for NodeJS lambda functions backed by DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, validation, lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

I was wondering which library to use for validating user input in lambda functions using e.g. the Serverless Framework, NodeJS lambda functions and DynamoDB as NoSQL storage. Especially, is there any library for NodeJS which can **detect and validate potential DynamoDB injection vectors**?

I did some research and came up with a few possibilities to do validation in NodeJS but I could not find any useful information regarding NodeJS with DynamoDB NoSQL injection validation:

1. Plain Javascript

```js
// lambda function handler
module.exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const data = JSON.parse(event.body);
  if (data.text && typeof data.text !== 'string') {
    // validation failure
  }
}
```

2. [Joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi)
3. [vadium-node](https://github.com/vandium-io/vandium-node) (uses Joi)
4. [validator-js](https://github.com/chriso/validator.js)

*(Of course this list is not complete but it seems that these are the most popular validation librarys for NodeJS.)*

Is there any library you know, which handles NoSQL injection detection for DynamoDB or do you have further informations about handling NoSQL injection vectors with one of those libraries (2-4)?

Comment: did you find the answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

For JSON format validations and to prevent injections, you can use AWS API Gateway [Models and Mapping Templates for Request and Response Mappings](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/models-mappings.html#models-mappings-mappings) which uses [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/) to define the models.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know about the mapping templates but what if those mappings aren't strictly enough to ensure that no injection vector can be passed to the lambda functions? Or does API Gateway models filter such injections beforehand? I didn't find any resource for that, therefore I didn't mentioned it in my posting.

Answer (score 0):

I used https://ajv.js.org/ to validate the event object. Once validated I use a mapper to create an entity.

EventDto -> AjvValidation -> EventMapper -> EventEntity

Once you get your EventEntity you are 100% sure the validation, sanitization, and types you work on are the right ones.